# QuickFIX: unexpected midnight sequence reset

Tags: python, quickfix

I have an issue with QuickFIX (v1.15.1)

QuickFIX runs 4 weekly sessions without reset on logon / logout.
I set the Start & End time & day like this

```
StartTime=15:00:00
EndTime=14:55:00
StartDay=sun
EndDay=sun
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnLogout=N
```

But QuickFIX resets every sunday at 00:00, it looks like the start & end time is not used. I can't reconnect afterwards cause the sequence numbers are not in sync anymore.

Does someone know what the problem is?

Update:

Here is some logs.
I replaced the sender & target. 
XXX = sender (me)
DST = target

```
20191221-23:59:59.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=0078|35=0|49=DST|56=XXX|34=12078|52=20191221-23:59:59.073|10=025|
20191222-00:00:00.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=78|35=5|34=12302|49=XXX|52=20191222-00:00:00.000|56=DST|10=138|
20191222-00:00:49.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=86|35=A|34=1|49=XXX|52=20191222-00:00:49.000|56=DST|98=0|108=30|10=244|
20191222-00:00:50.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=0131|35=5|49=DST|56=XXX|34=12080|52=20191222-00:00:49.971|58=MsgSeqNum too low, expecting 12303 but received 1|10=095|
20191222-00:00:50.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=74|35=5|34=2|49=XXX|52=20191222-00:00:50.000|56=DST|10=197|
```

Comment: IIRC then using StartDay and EndDay turns the session into a week-long session and ignores StartTime and EndTime.

Comment: Apart from that: are you sure you are using quickfix/N, i.e. for  .NET?

Comment: I use the quickfix from pypi https://pypi.org/project/quickfix/ (C++ with a Swig interface for python)

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn but it's working with the same configuration on two others envs.

Comment: So it is behaving differently on different systems with the same config?

Comment: And you are sure that *your* side of the connection resets the sequence numbers and not the counterparty (due to misconfiguration)? Do you have some logs that you can share from Sunday around 00:00?

Comment: The config. is not exactly the same, times and sessions name is different but I keep the same file everytime and just replace the target / sender.
I have edited the question and add some logs. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Did some research in the quickfix issue tracker and it seems that this is indeed a bug. [issue 261](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/issues/261)

Unfortunately no-one has replied yet. But sounds like the problem you are having.